Server Spring boot cannot parse the multipart request
Encountered an error Content-Type
There is a form on the front of the part and a file is attached to it

I have to accept the request from the front and process it. But when the front sends a request for service, we get an error:
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryn1nNr7iOEen0Aykw' is not supported]
I might have thought that the server was not accepting requests, but I tested it via postman and everything worked well


Front, for its part, tested requests to https://httpbin.org/#/HTTP_Methods/post_post and everything went well for them. the service sent a positive response.

This is what it looks like js file:
async function submitDataToBackend(data, file, formDataa) {
  const formatedFormData = dataFormattingIntoJSON(data);
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('form', formatedFormData);
  if (file) {
    formData.append('CV', file);
  }

  for (const pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log('key: ', pair[0], ';       value: ', pair[1]);
  }

  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

  fetch('http://localhost:8081/api/v1/forms/newproject', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: formData,
  })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('response from server: ', data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}

Server controller that processes the request
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/forms")
@Tag(name = "Forms Controller", description = "Forms API")
@Slf4j
public class FormsController {
    private final EmailServiceMarsNet emailServiceMarsNet;

    @PostMapping(value="/newproject",consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    @Operation(summary = "Method for send email form 'Start your NEW project'")
    public StartProjectDTO sendStartProjectRequest(@RequestPart(value = "form") @Valid StartProjectDTO request,
                                                   @RequestPart(value = "CV", required = false) MultipartFile file){
        log.info(request.toString());
        emailServiceMarsNet.sendFormStartYourProjectNew(request,file);
        return request;
    }
}

maybe I wrote the controller incorrectly?
if you need more information to understand the situation, write in the comments

Can you try using @RequestParm for the file instead of @RequestPart?

@kSp Yes I tried but I get the same error

There's a basic misunderstanding I think. You put a JSON String into your FormData-Object and expect Spring to deserialize that, it's not gonna work that way. You can modify your client code to put all the fields into FormData and then deserialize it using @ModelAttribute.
Adjustments to the Client Code:
async function submitDataToBackend(data, file, formDataa) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  // Append each data field as a form field
  Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    formData.append(key, data[key]);
  });
  if (file) {
    formData.append('CV', file);
  }

  // Print FormData for debugging
  for (const pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log('key: ', pair[0], ';       value: ', pair[1]);
  }

  fetch('http://localhost:8081/api/v1/forms/newproject', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData, // No headers field
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log('response from server: ', data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

Adjustments to the Controller:
public StartProjectDTO sendStartProjectRequest(@ModelAttribute StartProjectDTO request,
                                                   @RequestParam(value = "CV", required = false) MultipartFile file) {

Reference:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-controller/ann-methods/modelattrib-method-args.html
A different approach you could do is to change the expected type in your controller to String and deserialize it yourself using ObjectMapper.
If you want to go that way, which I would not recommend this would be the code:
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/forms")
@Tag(name = "Forms Controller", description = "Forms API")
@Slf4j
public class FormsController {
    private final EmailServiceMarsNet emailServiceMarsNet;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @PostMapping(value="/newproject",consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    @Operation(summary = "Method for send email form 'Start your NEW project'")
    public StartProjectDTO sendStartProjectRequest(@RequestPart(value = "form") String request,
                                                   @RequestPart(value = "CV", required = false) MultipartFile file){
        log.info(request.toString());
        StartProjectDTO startProjectDTO = objectMapper.readValue(request, StartProjectDTO.class);
        emailServiceMarsNet.sendFormStartYourProjectNew(request,file);
        return request;
    }
}

Also one thing to mention, since you are using Swagger you could go code-first approach for an OpenAPI Spec and generate the client-code to call your API automatically.
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator

When you have JSON and file in the same request you should use @RequestParam for JSON (respective Java object) and @RequestPart for the file. Try this:
public StartProjectDTO sendStartProjectRequest(
                   @RequestParam(value = "form") @Valid StartProjectDTO request,
                   @RequestPart(value = "CV", required = false) MultipartFile file)


Then I will get this error, supposedly I then get a string that cannot be converted to my object: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.marsnetsolution.mailsender.dto.StartProjectDTO'

If I leave @RequestPart, then I get the request from the postman, but not from the front part.

It’s the exact opposite of what Mar-Z wrote, @RequestPart should be used for complex structures like json, this is because of how its deserialized as described in the official documentation. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestPart.html

@ObserverUA Please check your DTO class. Do you have getters and setters for all fields? This is needed for default deserializer to work.

@kSp your statement is correct for Spring in general. But we have Spring Boot and Spring MVC here. The solution in my answer is correct and tested. The DTO need to have setters and getters for Jackcson mapper to work properly. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html

Sorry but I think you are mistaking here, it’s not about Spring MVC and Spring Boot. it’s about reactive (Spring WebFlux) and non-reactive (Spring MVC) it’s also described in the documentation from your link. You can use both approaches with Spring Boot either by having correct modules on your class path or if both needed by a proper configuration
